# Setgid() call return fail in JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am writting jni code for a netTV project apk. so I write code line like  setgid(AID_AUDIO) in jni to make the current process have right to write data to the audio devices.

The problem is the setgit(AID_AUDIO) return fail because a common apk program can have user permission. I know that common apk cannot access to any device over jni, but my question is: how can I get my apk have system or root permission?

Comment: Are you building your own platform, or just the application? Android applications don't talk to audio device directly, see http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/audio_sub_system.html I'd be surprised if any application was permitted to do `setgid()` like that.

Comment: I am helping our custormer to create a live TV apk, which will be runnng on our platform, they hope to swith TV channel very quickly.